# Node JS throwing the error "unhandled stream error in pipe"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looping through a lot of images I wish to download in Node JS.
But is bombs out at random places in the queue. I suspect its because I'm using .pipe incorrectly for multiple streams, but I'm not sure.

This is the point it bombs:

```
request(options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetPath)).on('close', callback)
```

Would that be the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting a stream error because you're not handling the `error` event.

Add the following (for further debugging):

```
request(options)
    .pipe(
        fs.createWriteStream(targetPath))
        .on('error', myErrorHandler) // <--- This bit
        .on('close', callback)
    )
```